# Port Forwarding not working on Ubuntu system with Skyworth residential router

Tags: ubuntu, router, port-forwarding, iptables

I am working on Ubuntu 20.04 .

I enabled port forwarding on my router as follows :
[image: Port Forwarding]

With a static local IP address configuration as follows :
[image: IP address]

Following the instructions here : https://portforward.com/skyworth/residential-gateway/

I run `nc -kl 3390` on my computer. I have disabled `ufw` , and there are no rules in `iptables`. But when I go to https://canyouseeme.org/ , and enter port number 3390, it shows :

```
Error: I could not see your service on ***.***.***.**(my public IP) on port (3390)
```

What could be the reason for this ?

Comment: What service exactly are you trying to configure to run on your system?

Comment: @Ramhound This https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64955265/port-forwarding-not-working-with-socket-programming-in-python

Comment: That link doesn't answer my question.

Comment: @Ramhound I am only trying to make a TCP connection with sockets in python. Nothing more.